# A couple of 101 questions about indexes in SQL, specifically tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing

**Scenario 1:**

I have a non-clustered index on (`OrderDate, Country, OrderStatus`)

I imagine that if I search by `OrderDate`, `OrderDate/Country` or `OrderDate/Country/Status` then that index can be used. What about if I'm just searching by `OrderDate/OrderStatus` or `OrderStatus`?

**Scenario 2:**

I have 3 separate non-clustered indexes on `OrderDate`, `Country` and `OrderStatus`

If my query involves all 3 of those columns, then can it take advantage of all 3 indexes? What I mean is, after filtering with the best index it chooses, can it then take advantage of the other 2 indexes?

This information will help me to not over implement indexes.

Thanks

**ETA:** Just to add, this is for a typical order search page with about 30 different filters.

Comment: For scenario 1: the search ON `OrderDate/OrderStatus` might use the index - for `OrderDate`. But the search on only `OrderStatus` **cannot** use the index. A compound index *might* be used if the *n left-most columns* in that index are being searched on (where n >= 1)

Comment: Thanks, that's inline with my belief for scenario 1

Comment: @marc_s: Actually for only `OrderStatus` it can use the index. It'll scan through it when it does and use look up if you need more information than present in the index.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to Scenario 1 is actually a bit more complex than that.

It also comes down to what is selected from the 'search' and how the data is distributed in the table. But seeing as this is 101 I'll not go too deep into it.

Basically - if you select columns included in your index, with `OrderDate` first, and only select the columns included in the index (meaning columns in the index and included columns), it'll use the index you specified and it should be able to do a `seek` (fastest way to look up data, as it can seek through the index to the correct leaf nodes)

If you `SELECT *` or otherwise select a lot of columns that is not in your index, with `OrderDate` first, then it'll maybe not use your index because another index is better - or depending on the data it'll do a `seek` on your index, combined with a key look up.
And this is where it can get much more complex, but where I cannot remember the exact numbers off the top of my head.

If you select using `OrderStatus` then again depending on what you actually select, you can either use the index or not. But when using the index it'll `scan` it because it cannot seek.
(*Scan means running through each leaf node in the index*)
And again - it might combine with a key lookup to get the data not included in the index, if selecting data not from the index.

I hope this helps a bit with scenario 1. Otherwise I would advice you to go over to https://dba.stackexchange.com/ for more database related audience.

As for how you mention your scenario 2; then the short answer is that if your query involves all 3 indexes, it'll properly not take advantage of all 3 unless your query is build using unions or otherwise temporary structures (common table expressions etc).

It *is* possible that the optimizer will join the query for the indexes together, but more 
often than not, you're more likely to see it using just the one index.

Comment: Not sure about your statement on scenario 2: the query optimizer *can* combine multiple indices to speed up searches ....

Comment: It would require - as mentioned - more information about the query to say much with certainty about it. But yes, you're right - it *can*. I'll amend my answer

Comment: @Allan, I will be selecting lots more columns. I've added an ETA to my question that says this is for an order search page. I'll do a search on some of your terminology and see if I have any more questions.